# dynamic_casting of objects confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

The book [The c++ programming language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840) has sections about dynamic_cast that I'm not sure I understand correctly.

> The purpose of dynamic_cast is to deal with the case in which the correctness of the conversion cannot be determined by the compiler. In that case, dynamic_cast(p) looks at the object pointed to by p (if any). If that object is of class T or has a unique base class of type T, then dynamic_cast returns a pointer of type T* to that object; otherwise, nullptr is returned. If the value of p is nullptr, dynamic_cast(p) returns nullptr. Note the requirement that the conversion must be to a uniquely identified object. It is possible to construct examples where the conversion fails and nullptr is returned because the object pointed to by p has more than one subobject representing bases of type T.

Does "It is possible to construct examples where the conversion fails and nullptr is returned because the object pointed
to by p has more than one subobject representing bases of type T" mean something like this?

```
class a {
public:
    a() { }
};

class b : public a {
public:
    b() { }
};

class z : public a, public b {
public:
    z() { }
};

void f(z* p) {
    a* x = dynamic_cast<a*>(p); // ambiguous
}
```

And another one, this is taken from the book:

```
class Component : public virtual Storable { /* ... */ };
class Receiver : public Component { /* ... */ };
class Transmitter : public Component { /* ... */ };
class Radio : public Receiver, public Transmitter { /* ... */ };
```

> The ambiguity for a pointer to a Radio object is not in general detectable at compile time.
>
> This kind of run-time ambiguity detection is needed only for virtual bases. For ordinary bases, there is always a unique subobject of a given cast (or none) when downcasting (that is, toward a derived class; §22.2). The equivalent ambiguity for virtual bases occurs when upcasting (that is, toward a base), but such ambiguities are caught at compile time.

I totally don't understand this. What does this mean "For ordinary bases, there is always a unique subobject of a given cast"? I understand if the base is not virtual a subobject will be created for each class that derive from it. But in terms of casting, I just caused an ambiguity error with my above example. And "The equivalent ambiguity for virtual bases occurs when upcasting", what does that mean? Can virtual bases be ambiguous? Can anyone explain this clearer?

Comment: There is only one child `z` of a given `a`, unless you use `virtual` base.

Comment: @Yakk
 what are you refering to?

Comment: your classes a and z above?

Comment: @Yakk ah, yes I know. Any instance of a class deriving from "a" will each have a subobject of "a" unless "a" is a virtual base then "a" is shared. But the quotes I quoted in my question are very confusing to me.

Comment: No.  A given base object `a` of base type `A`, if it has a `B` subclass, the`b` subobject, that subobject will be unique.  There is no way to cast ambiguously from `a` to `b`.  You csn upcast ambigupusky from `z` to `b` or `a`, but you cannot downcast ambiguously (without `virtual` inheritance).  Your 'counter example' is *upcasting*, which does not contradict a sentence about *downcasting*.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure what you mean. I never said you can cast ambiguously from a to b. That's not my example, which as you said, is upcasting. I believe the first quote refers to upcasting, that's why I wrote the code with classes a, b and z to find out if that's what the sentence "It is possible to construct examples where the conversion fails and nullptr is returned because the object pointed
to by p has more than one subobject representing bases of type T." is refering to.

Comment: I understand that you are wrong, but saying so again doen't help.  `"For ordinary bases, there is always a unique subobject of a given cast"` is about downcasting.  Your 'but I created ambiguity' is about upcasting.  You are barking the up a tree, you should be barking down.

Comment: @Yakk I posted two quotes in my question. My last comment directly refers to the first quote, directly before the declaration of class a. In your last comment you are referring to the second quote, directly after the declaration of class radio. I'm talking about the first quote in the book, which I think talks about upcasting. I thought you are referring to the first quote as well, that's why I don't understand what you mean, I didn't know you're referring to the last quote, which indeed talks about downcasting. Sorry about that misunderstanding. What about ambiguity with virtual bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **”** For ordinary [non-virtual] bases, there is always a unique subobject of a given cast (or none) when downcasting (that is, toward a derived class; §22.2

That's because non-virtual inheritance creates a strict hierarchy of derived classes, where branches don't come together again. An object must be of some most derived class `T`, down at a leaf node of that tree of classes. Going up, you can't encounter `T` again, because a class cannot inherit from itself. Thus, with a dynamic cast down to `T`, you will end up with the object's most derived class. And similarly for any class in the (or each) inheritance chain.

Comment: And what about this quote "The equivalent ambiguity for virtual bases occurs when upcasting but such ambiguities are caught at compile time." What does this mean?

Comment: It means that if you are upcasting e.g. from `D&` to `B&`, and there are two or more base classes of type `B`, then that's known at compile time. In the opposite direction, casting down from `B&` to `D&`, it's not known at compile time whether there is 0, 1 or more `D` sub-object, because this depends on the most derived type of the object currently bound to the reference. The `dynamic_cast` has to figure that out based on type information emitted by the compiler, and either succeed, or give you a nullpointer, or for cast to reference, an exception.